# How do I enable the Wi-Fi as a primary network tool in Kali Linux?

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, monitoring, ethernet, internet

While installing Kali Linux there was an option to choose a primary network between Ethernet and Wireless network. But since my device has a problem with wireless I opted for Ethernet. Now, I have bought a new wifi adapter from TP-link, I still cannot access it to use the internet. It shows up when I plug but there is a message like this...

> Wifi Network(Ralink)

> Wifi is disabled

Furthermore, I can use this adapter in monitor mode and it works fine with **wifite** tool but I cannot run it normally for the internet.

So please help me run the internet using this external wifi adapter. How do I proceed?

Comment: maybe the best way to proceed is to install a user friendly linux distribution, such as Ubuntu or Mint

Comment: Thanks but that is not an option here because I am trying to learn ethical hacking. After all, we learn from small things that go wrong so please help me overcome this instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the wifi adapter is correctly installed

Then use this command:

> sudo nmtui

to activate a wifi connection and set the DHCP or static IP

**Note**:
In Linux for all distributions, there is no primary or secondary ethernet.
But you can use the default route (to 0.0.0.0) to ethernet or wifi connection.it is simply added gateway to your connection.

For example:

if you set the default route or gateway in a wifi connection, All traffic is passed through the wifi.